# NFA without ε-transitions which recognizes the language generated by the regular expression

Tags: automata

NFA without ε-transitions
which recognises the language generated by the regular expression:

1(0 + 0(10)*0)0

[here is what i've done so far..](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Crdyv.png)

Comment: Do you know to convert regular expressions to NFA? It's a standard application of this procedure.

Comment: yes, but im kinda stuck with this problem...

Answer (score 1):

Here is a possible NFA for the language $1(0 + 0(10)^*0)0$:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you can add a branch in second 0-transitions to take a union operation. It is feasible in NFA. [Here is a required NFA.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NH8pj.png)

Comment: are u sure about your answer?

Comment: I think your addition operation is union operation on Sipser's Book. Is there any problem?

Comment: Your automaton does not seem to accept $1000$.